# Calculating Increasing Based on Value in Column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have column like this :

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wshbW.png)

```
select date(created_at) datee, count(*) video_count 
from test_ambil_nihongo_doang_loop_jan2023
where month(video_time_published) = 1 and year(video_time_published) = 2023
group by date(created_at)
```

and i want to Calculating Increasing value from video_count column, so i get the new column called increment like this

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igLkE.png)

im using MYSQL, please give me solution to solve this. thanks

im expecting to get value in increment columns

Comment: Please can you edit your question, and share your simple data as text instead of images, so it can be easy for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have a primary key called `id`, and also presuming that you want the `increment` column to be relative to the previous day (not necessarily the previous row), then this might work for you.

For each row, we look for entries from the same table that have a `created_at` date of the previous day.  Because this will multiply the rows (before aggregation), we add `DISTINCT` clauses to the counts so we don't double count.

```
select
  date(t.created_at) datee,
  count(DISTINCT t.id) video_count,
  count(DISTINCT t.id) - count(DISTINCT s.id) increment
from test_ambil_nihongo_doang_loop_jan2023 t
left join test_ambil_nihongo_doang_loop_jan2023 s
   ON month(s.video_time_published) = month(t.video_time_published)
   AND year(s.video_time_published) = year(t.video_time_published)
   AND date(s.created_at) = date_sub(t.created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
where month(t.video_time_published) = 1
and year(t.video_time_published) = 2023
group by date(t.created_at)
```